# Ho can I return multiple arrays with laravel API?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, backend, chat

Hello evryone Actually I'm following an MVP which has juste the frontend with reactJs and I'm trying to develop the backend side with laravel.
And now, I'm on real time chat .when I log the frontend response I get this response:

```
{chatsContacts: Array(2), contacts: Array(10), profileUser: {…}}
```

This is what I get When I try to follow the mvp response :

```
(3) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
```

This is my code on backend side :

```
  function listChats(){
       
    function listChats(){
       
        $types= chat::all();
        $c= chat::all();
        $d= chat::all();

        foreach ($types as $chats) {
            $chats->chatsContacts = chat::all()->where('user_id', $chats->user_id); 
        }
        foreach ($c as $chats) {
            $chats->chat = chat::all()->where('user_id', $chats->user_id);    
        }
        foreach ($d as $chats) {
            $chats->profileUser = chat::all()->where('user_id', $chats->user_id); ;    
        }            

                
        return [$types, $c,$d];
  }            
        }
        return $types;
  }
```

I would be very thankful if anyone of you help mee getting the same result as the MVP.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please understand no of database queries here - at least 6 queries  **chat::all()** - fetch all chat records with all columns . No of rows in chats database may grow pretty fast & then there could be serious performance issues with 6 duplicate queries. Include more info like what are `chatsContacts`, `contacts`, which models are defined how are the relations defined? Then you may get useful good suggestions.

Comment: @Donkarnash yes I know it's not good for the performance but I try it juste for testing and then I will fetch only what I need

Answer (score 1):

Your backend code example is a bit confusing, I'm pretty sure the exact code posted here would not work. It would be more helpful to just post the whole controller code instead of just this little snippet.

However, it seems to me the fix would be to replace the line

`return [$types, $c,$d];`

with

`return ['chatContacts' => $types, 'contacts' => $c, 'profileUser' => $d];`

php arrays can have numeric or associative keys. When you don't define associative keys, php uses numeric keys by default. However, in Javascript, array keys can only be numeric. So if you want to use associative arrays, the closest thing you can get is an object of arrays. Like your first code example.

When converting an associative php array to JSON, the result will be what you're looking for. An object with named properties containing your arrays.

Also, I would recommend against using one letter variable names. Try describing the contents of your variables. Something like `$contacts` and `$profileUser`.